# Using PHP DOM want to show all string as a output

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-replace, preg-match

> Here, is my html string in $data variable in php,  and that string
>   have some text like `<140/90 mmHg OR <130/80 mmHg`  this line not
>   showing when i run this code using PHP `DOMDocument` because when coming less-than & grater-than signs its problematic.

```
<?php
$data = 'THE CORRECT ANSWER IS C.
<p>Choice A Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
<p></p>
<p>Choice B Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
<p>Choice D Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
<p></p>
<p>Choice E simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p></p>
<p><br>THIS IS MY MAIN TITLE IN CAPS<br>This my sub title.</p>
<p><br>TEST ABC: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p>1) It is a long established fact <140/90 mmHg OR <130/80 mmHg making it look like readable English will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
<br><br>2) There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available. </p>
<p><br>TEST XYZ: Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<p><br>TES T TEST: It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<p><br>TESTXXX: It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>';
echo boldFormatExplanation($data);
?>
```

> Also, i have created below PHP function that will convert bold title
>   and bold some words using PHP `DOMDocument`.
>
> 1. Title with bold: "THIS IS MY MAIN TITLE IN CAPS" (title not always same)
> 2. Words with bold: TEST ABC:, TEST XYZ:, TES T TEST:, TESTXXX: (this words are always same)
>
> this above 2 points working well just missing line as i have
>   described above in first block.

```
<?php
function boldFormatExplanation($data){
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
    $dom->substituteEntities = false;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);// Set error level
    @$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);// Load html
    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);// Restore error level
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);// Dom xpath
    $title_flag = true;
    foreach($xpath->query('//text()') as $node) {
        $txt = trim($node->nodeValue);
        $p = $node->parentNode;
        if (preg_match("/^\s*(TEST ABC:|TEST XYZ:|TES T TEST:|TESTXXX)(.*)$/s", $node->nodeValue, $matches)) {
            // Put Choice in bold:
            $p->insertBefore($dom->createElement('b', $matches[1]), $node);
            $node->nodeValue = " " . trim($matches[2]);
        } else 
        if (strtoupper($txt) === $txt && $txt !== '') {
            // Put header in bold
            if($title_flag == true){
                $p->insertBefore($dom->createElement('b', $txt), $node);
                $node->nodeValue = "";
                $title_flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    $domData = $dom->saveHTML();
    $data = htmlspecialchars_decode($domData);
    return $data; 
} ?>
```

You can run this code at [here](https://3v4l.org/IA9Ab), also the output skipping this line `<140/90 mmHg OR <130/80 mmHg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the choice here, you need to process the string before loading it with `DOMDocument::loadHTML`. But you can't do it like a barbarian with a blind replacement *(because in this case `<` between `script` or `style` tags would be replaced too)*. You need to use the libxml errors to locate only problematic opening angle brackets. You can do it this way *(it isn't fast since you need to build the DOM tree until the errors disappear but it's correct)*:

```
define('LIBXML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED', 68);

$skeleton = '<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/></head><body id="root">%s</body></html>';
$htmlDoc = sprintf($skeleton, $data);

$dom = new DOMDocument;

do {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $hasError = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($htmlDoc);
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        if ($error->code == LIBXML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED) {
            $hasError = true;
            $htmlDoc = preg_replace('~\A(?:.*\R){' . ($error->line - 1) . '}.{' . ($error->column - 2) . '}\K<~u', '&lt;', $htmlDoc);
        }
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
} while ($hasError);

boldFormatExplanation($dom);

foreach($dom->getElementById('root')->childNodes as $childNode) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}
```

As an aside, it's useless to set DOMDocument encoding property when you use `DOMDocument::loadHTML` after, because the encoding is set with document content *(this is the main reason I put myself an html skeleton around `$data` with `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`)*.

About your bold function, you can write it this way:

```
function boldFormatExplanation(&$dom) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $title_flag = true;

    foreach($xpath->query('//text()') as $node) {
        $txt = trim($node->nodeValue);
        if (empty($txt)) continue;

        $p = $node->parentNode;
        if (preg_match("/^(TEST ABC:|TEST XYZ:|TES T TEST:|TESTXXX)\s*(.*)/s", $txt, $matches)) {
            // Put Choice in bold:
            $p->insertBefore($dom->createElement('b', $matches[1]), $node);
            $node->nodeValue = " " . $matches[2];
        } elseif ($title_flag && strtoupper($txt) === $txt) {
            // Put header in bold
            $p->replaceChild($dom->createElement('b', $txt), $node);
            $title_flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, its working good, sometime while break and shows errors? and also i am trying to make bold 1st and 2nd point as i have needed to this function.

Comment: @Rocky: You need to start with this code, and only after apply your bold function. What errors are displayed?

Comment: Can you add bold things from my function with your ?

Comment: Right now while loop is not showing any errors but in feature it comes ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and now its working well.